# SMPlayer X11 Output Flickering

Tags: gnome, xorg, smplayer

I'm currently Using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and everything works fine but SMPlayer with X11 video output flickering when movie showing fast motion. (for example when camera moving relatively fast). Unfortunately I can not take screenshot to show you because every time I hit print screen the screenshot has no problem.

I had the same problem on:

- XFCE but after installing [compton](http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/) the problem solved.
- Unity but solved with disabling Unredirect fullscreen windows on Compiz.

I thought maybe it's OpenGL and disabled "allow flipping" but nothing changed.

I don't know why but sometimes GNOME effects being laggy and most of the time they are very fast and good. sometimes I see the same problem with gnome effects. Like closing window effect. but this kind of flickering often happening on the SMPlayer with X11 Video Output.

I also don't have `xserver-xorg-video-intel` installed.

I tried all video outputs on the SMPlayer but X11 have the best picture quality among them. also opengl, opengl-hq and vdpau on the toggling full screen showing some frozen frame from the past on the screen for like 1sec.

**Video Card**

GeForce GTX 660 Ti

**Installed Driver**

Nvidia-375.39

**Preferences**

Video > Output driver: X11

Video > Double buffering: ON (Off can not solve the problem)

Performance > Hardware decoding: None (Enabling it can not solve the problem)

Comment: are you specifically trying to use `X11` ? it's recommended by *smplayer* devs to combine `vdpau` + `mpv` for *nvidia* to achive the best video quality out of *smplayer* and `X11` is *slow* by itself to improve the *performance* you can add more threads to decoding depending on your *CPU* go to *smplayer* --> *settings* --> *performance* and add more threads to *decoding*

Comment: @JoKeR Tried many different settings. I set threats to 8 and Hardware decoding to the Auto. Have the same problem. Also set video output driver to the User Defined `vdpau,mpv` or `mpv,vdpau`. still have frozen frame problem as I explaned for opengl, opengl-hq and vdpau. Still getting better picture quality with X11. I don't know why but on XFCE installing compton solved the problem. Maybe I need to do something to Mutter? I have the same problem sometimes with gnome effects.